# math Critcl function vs math expr

Tags: tcl

I try to implement a simple addition with the help of `critcl` my goal is to retrieve a list of 3 values. I am surprised that the calculation time is not drastically reduced.

- ≈+25% less time per 1.000.000 calculation.
- ≈+100% time lost per 1.000 calculation

`puts [time {for {set i 0} {$i < 1000} {incr i} {AddCritcl {12 0 0} {12 0 13}}} 1]`
`puts [time {for {set i 0} {$i < 1000} {incr i} {AddTcl {12 0 0} {12 0 13}}} 1]`
`puts [time {for {set i 0} {$i < 1000000} {incr i} {AddCritcl {12 0 0} {12 0 13}}} 1]`
`puts [time {for {set i 0} {$i < 1000000} {incr i} {AddTcl {12 0 0} {12 0 13}}} 1]`

Even for a simple calculation like this (+400% time lost per 1.000.000 calculation):

```
critcl::cproc quadruple {int i} int {
    return i * 4; 
}
```

I am an amateur with C language, so that’s why I ask for help to know if my procedure `critcl::cproc AddCritcl` is well written ? If yes, other factors can be taken into account in the calculation time ?

Below my tcl Add procedure and my Critcl Add function :

```
proc AddTcl {p1 p2} {
    lassign $p1 x1 y1 z1
    lassign $p2 x2 y2 z2

    set px [expr {$x1 + $x2}]
    set py [expr {$y1 + $y2}]
    set pz [expr {$z1 + $z2}]

    return [list $px $py $pz]
}

critcl::cproc AddCritcl {Tcl_Interp* interp Tcl_Obj* Pt1 Tcl_Obj* Pt2} ok {

    int i;
    double p1[3], p2[3], p[3];
    Tcl_Obj **lp;

    if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, Pt1, &i, &lp) != TCL_OK) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    if (i != 3) {
        Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 2, lp, NULL);
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    while (i-->0) {
        if (Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, lp[i], &p1[i]) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }
    }

    if (Tcl_ListObjGetElements(interp, Pt2, &i, &lp) != TCL_OK) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    if (i != 3) {
        Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 2, lp, NULL);
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    while (i-->0) {
        if (Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, lp[i], &p2[i]) != TCL_OK) {
            return TCL_ERROR;
        }
    }

    p[0] = p1[0] + p2[0];
    p[1] = p1[1] + p2[1];
    p[2] = p1[2] + p2[2];


    Tcl_Obj *Pti = Tcl_NewListObj (0,0);

    Tcl_ListObjAppendElement (interp, Pti, Tcl_NewDoubleObj(p[0]));
    Tcl_ListObjAppendElement (interp, Pti, Tcl_NewDoubleObj(p[1]));
    Tcl_ListObjAppendElement (interp, Pti, Tcl_NewDoubleObj(p[2]));

    Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Pti);

    return TCL_OK;
}
```

Comment: Just to check, you're not including the time to call either of those the first time in those timing figures? You don't want to include the time (on _either_ side) to compile things; that's a one-off cost.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't expect there to be a lot of difference in speed for something this simple, as the cost of all the value boxing and unboxing will dominate in both cases. The more complex the mathematical transformation, the more you'll benefit from compiling.

Comment: *You're not including the time to call either of those the first time in those timing figures?* @DonalFellows I had tested before writing this message.

Comment: *The more complex the mathematical transformation, the more you'll benefit from compiling* Ok, I understand... But I thought even simple calculations would have a benefit like using my function `quadruple` with other *critcl* functions

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure where the extra cost may be coming from, but it's possible that it's due to inefficient list building (that's the only thing that's stand-out different).

I'd expect this to maybe be better:

```c
// Lots of bits the same
Tcl_Obj *outPts[3];

outPts[0] = Tcl_NewDoubleObj(p[0]);
outPts[1] = Tcl_NewDoubleObj(p[1]);
outPts[2] = Tcl_NewDoubleObj(p[2]);
Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewListObj(3, outPts));
// and the end of the function is the same too
```

The advantage here is that there is only one memory allocation done off-stack to create the list.

Also, since you care about working with floating point values, you should test your timings with floating point values. That may have an impact (more on the Tcl side, where you're timing with integer math right now, which isn't a fair comparison).

Comment: Thank you for correcting my code , and pointing out my mistakes , it doesn’t change much in improving my performance but it’s interesting to know how to do it differently .